# Comparing dates as strings and integers in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

My task is to compare dates in two different tables in a Teradata database. In table group_1 dates are BIGINT, for instance 20,141,106 and in table group_2 dates are VARCHAR(30), for instance, 11/12/2015.

What would be the best way to do a conversion and compare them, namely, 
select * from .... 
where date in group_1 = date in group_2?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert date types to date for comparisons and other operations.

For the integer:

```
select to_date(convert(bigintcol as varchar(255)), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

For the string:

```
select to_date(varcharcol, 'MM/DD/YYYY') -- or perhaps DD/MM/YYYY
```

You can then compare the dates directly.

Comment: Thanks, man. I am already implementing it. But when I do, say to_date(8/12/2015, mm/dd/yyyy) I get 8/12/2015 00:00:00.00000. Any way to trim it in order to get only the 8/12/2015 part?

Comment: Got it! cast(to_date(8/12/2015, mm/dd/yyyy) as date) does it. Thanxxx.

Answer (score 0):

Can you safely convert those columns to dates (no invalid dates)?

```
BIGINT -> DATE:
cast(col - 19000000 as date)

VARCHAR -> DATE:
to_date(col, 'dd/mm/yyyy') (or 'mm/dd/yyyy'?)
```

Otherwise:

```
BIGINT -> VARCHAR:
TRIM((col MOD 100) * 1000000 + (col/100 MOD 100) * 10000 + (col / 10000) (FORMAT '99/99/9999')) -- dmy
or
TRIM((col/100 MOD 100) * 1000000 + (col MOD 100) * 10000 + (col / 10000) (FORMAT '99/99/9999')) -- mdy
```

And next time, try to store data using the correct datatype or at least the same wrong type :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's what happens when you play with tables made by others :) I'm currently implementing it, but when I do, say to_date(8/12/2015, mm/dd/yyyy) I get 8/12/2015 00:00:00.00000. Any way to trim it in order to get only the 8/12/2015 part?

Comment: @DiegoMenezes: TO_DATE returns a DATE, what's your TD release and which client do you use?

Comment: Got it! cast(to_date(8/12/2015, mm/dd/yyyy) as date) does it. Thanxxx.